# Relevant Http Response Code using graphql-js

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Ok here's the thing, I'm trying to figure out how to deal with error handling with graphql-js. (In a case without Relay)

Not specific enough !? Ok so, since graphql-js is catching all errors thrown within resolve functions, I'm kind of confuse on how to deal properly with errors and http responses.

So I had few ideas and would like to know what you think about it !

1. Always return 200 OK with the graphql response even if containing errors. (Don't like that one)
2. Switch case on the result.errors[0] and return an http response in respect of the error, returning result.data if no errors. (which could end up being a veeeery long switch case)
3. - Deal with the error handling in the resolve function and throw and object (e.g. `{ httpCode: 404, msg: 'No X found with the requested id' }` )
   - In the express app.post function(or whatever web framework), having something like:

     ```
     app.post('/graphql', function(req, res) {
       let result = await graphql(req.body);

       if(result.errors.size) {
         let e = result.errors[0];
         res.status(e.httpCode).send(e.msg);
       }

       res.json(result.data);
     }
     ```

   This doesn't currently work because of the way the error object is marshalled... or at least I haven't found how to get it out of graphql yet. I'm thinking of maybe looking into graphql-js source but I thought I better ask you guys first since I might be missing something obvious.

Obviously, a better idea is welcome !

Cheers :D

Answer (score 1):

I am also trying to figure this out.

The best I have managed to come up with is throwing a custom error in my resolver. Check out [apollo-errors](https://github.com/thebigredgeek/apollo-errors). I am not sure if this is the best way, but it could work for you.